# “including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!” want to remove it. console warning

Tags: ruby, capybara, integration-testing

To resolve the error visit is not found. I have included include Capybara::DSL in one of my helper module like this: 
I am using ruby 2.7.0

```
include Capybara::DSL

module LoginHelper
  def self.login_user
    visit 'https://staging.have2have.it/login'  
    within(".container-fluid") do
      fill_in("email", with: 'shinsaurab@gmail.com', :match => :prefer_exact)
      fill_in("password", with: '123', :match => :prefer_exact)
    end
    click_button('Log In')
  end
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require './spec/helpers/login_helper'

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include LoginHelper
end
```

Can anyone please suggest if I am doing something wrong. I have tried some suggestion but didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar issue tried many things but what worked for me is to remove config.include Capybara::DSL from spec_helper and include the LoginHelper in a Helpers module. In your case, they may look like this:

login_helper.rb

```
module Helpers
  module LoginHelper
    def login_user
      visit 'https://staging.have2have.it/login'  
      within(".container-fluid") do
        fill_in("email", with: 'shinsaurab@gmail.com', :match => :prefer_exact)
        fill_in("password", with: '123', :match => :prefer_exact)
      end
      click_button('Log In')
    end
  end
end
```

And spec_helper will look like this:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require './spec/helpers/login_helper.rb'

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Helpers::LoginHelper
end
```

Thanks!
Please let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me but I don't know why? can you please explain why we have removed config.include Capybara::DSL.